# Giphy API not responding in discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I made a discord bot that shows you gifs when you type a certain command but the problem is that it works fine in the first half but takes a long time to show the gifs when not used.
Basically it doesn't show the gifs instantly when not used.
Here's the code that I've written:

@client.command()

async def gif(ctx, *, q = 'dance'):

```
api_key = 'Some Key here'
api_instanc = giphy_client.DefaultApi()

try:
    api_responce = api_instanc.gifs_search_get(api_key, q, limit = 7,rating = 'r')
    lst = list(api_responce.data)
    giff = random.choice(lst)
    emb = discord.Embed(title = f"Requested by {ctx.author} " + q )
    emb.set_image(url= f'https://media.giphy.com/media/{giff.id}/giphy.gif')

    await ctx.channel.send(embed = emb)
except ApiException as e:
    await ctx.channel.send("API EXCEPTION")
```

It doesn't show any errors but doesn't work after the long time.
Any re-write of the code with aiohttp will be appreciated because I am learning that.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Blocking [read more](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#what-does-blocking-mean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the module you are using is not asynchronous which leads to blocking [read more](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#what-does-blocking-mean).

Default in the command is `search = None` you can use that with an if statement to check.

After that is the request for the api to get the image.

Here is the code edited to use `aiohttp`

```py
# import aiohttp
# import random

@bot.command()
async def giphy(ctx, search: str = None):
    api_key = ""
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Requested by {ctx.author}")
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        # search
        if search:
            embed.description = search
            async with session.get(f'http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q={search}&api_key={api_key}&limit=10') as response:
                data = await response.json()
                gif_choice = random.randint(0, 9)
                embed.set_image(url=data['data'][gif_choice]['images']['original']['url'])
        # radnom
        else:
            async with session.get(f'http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/random?api_key={api_key}&limit=10') as response:
                data = await response.json()
                embed.set_image(url=data['data']['images']['original']['url'])

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```